# How to create new log file for every user by logging Django

Tags: python, django, logging, python-logging

I have logger for every user if he`s log in and log out

How am i suppose to say logger create every time new file for each user with his nickname. I dont need all info about all users in one log file i want to split it by different files

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'log_in_out_format': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'log_in_out_file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'loggers/log_in_out/log.log',
            'formatter': 'log_in_out_format',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'authentication': {
            'handlers': ['log_in_out_file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        }
    },
}
```

in views.py i have something like that:

```
login(request, user)
logger.info(f'{request.user.email} logged in ')
```

```
logger.warning(f'{request.user.email} logged out')
logout(request)
```

Comment: No idea, but perhaps it's just as quick and easy to print the user name with each logging statement, and grep on the relevant lines? Or use a database for relevant statements, with a username field.

Comment: I doubt it's a workable idea, since you normally create the logger (and logging file) when you start up the application. Creating a new logger and corresponding file each time a user logs in (and closing the file if the user logs out) seems like it would complicate the code more than it likely needs to be.

Comment: Also, mostly: you want the logging to about the app, the code, what it's doing, (correct or wrong), and store that information. Actions about individual users tend to go in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its possible bcs logger can create one log file and it cant handle creating multiple log files for different users

You can try to create method to save info about log in/log out in your db its gotta be better